# How can I use PromiseKit w/ Race to return the quickest result

Tags: swift, asynchronous, promisekit

I have a network request. I'd like to make this request and fallback to a cached value if

- the request fails
- the request takes too long

I was thinking I could use `race` to make the request and also use `after` to give myself a sort of time out on the promise.

Something like -

```swift
  func getCompany() -> Promise<Company> {

    let request: Promise<Company> = client.request(.getCompany)
    let cachedResponse: Promise<Company?> = cache.getObject(ofType: Company.self, forKey: "company")

    return race(request, after(seconds: 4).then(cachedResponse))
  }
```

This fails to compile however with

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Promise<Company?>' to expected argument type '(Void) -> Guarantee<_>'
```

I'd like to say essentially return the first one that resolves, which in this case would be `cachedResponse` if `request` took longer than 4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things you will need to do first. It looks like one of your requests return an optional, you will need to handle this in some way as `race` is going to require all promises to conform to the same type.

If you are planning on using this approach elsewhere, I would suggest creating a simple util to wrap around the delayed response.

```swift
func await<T>(for delay: TimeInterval, then body: Promise<T>) -> Promise<T> {
  return after(seconds: delay).then { _ in body }
}
```

You can then refactor your `getCompany` method to race your requests as:

```swift
  func getCompany() -> Promise<Company?> {
    let request: Promise<Company?> = client.request(.getCompany)
    let cachedResponse: Promise<Company?> = await(for: 2, then: cache.getObject(ofType: Company.self, forKey: "company"))

    return race(request, cachedResponse)
  }
```